# Google Classroom API - Very slow

Tags: google-classroom

Getting students in a class (of 30-40 students) takes anywhere from 7-14 seconds per page.

I even tried the "Try It!" feature at this URL and it's taking around 7 seconds
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list

- Excluded some fields but it did not help.
- Tried decreasing the page size from 30 to 10, and each call is now 3 seconds, but has to be called 3 more times.

#### Update: 7/19/2016

The new APIs are just as slow. Creating CourseWork takes 3-4 seconds. Any idea why?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/"
       + courseId 
       + "/courseWork?alt=json&key="
       + apiKey,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      title: assignmentName,  
      materials: [  
         {'link': { 'url': assignmentUrl }} 
      ],  
      workType: 'ASSIGNMENT',  
      state: 'PUBLISHED',  
    }),
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    },
    success: ...,
    error: ...
});
```

Comment: Is this still happening? That's very much slower than it should be.

Comment: Yes, I have a class of 38 students and getting the first page of 30 students consistently takes 6 seconds and the second page of 8 students consistently takes 3 seconds.

Comment: @mjs New APIs are performing just as slow (please see my update). I'm located in Seattle.